# In Linux replace \n with \n\n from text (file)

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Let say we have simple text

```
aaaa
bbbb 
cccc
```

Output:

```
aaaa

bbbb

cccc
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed G file
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just this `awk`

```
awk '{print $0"\n"}' file
aaaa

bbbb

cccc
```

Or this:

```
awk 1 ORS="\n\n" file
aaaa

bbbb

cccc
```

Or this:

```
awk '$0=$0"\n"' file
aaaa

bbbb

cccc
```

Comment: +1 for a solid solution. I do wish you'd written it as `awk -v ORS='\n\n' '1' file` though.

Comment: @EdMorton The long debate on where to put the variable :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I've given up on you now and will leave you to your yoda-like scripting (`given up on you, I have` = `do stuff with X, init X`) :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Never give opp, it just take some time :)  PS is there any reason on why quote the `1` like this `'1'`

Comment: I can't think of any negative to not quoting it for this specific case other than you might forget to add the quotes later if/when your requirements change, e.g. if you had to only print non-blank lines you might change `awk 1 file` to `awk $0 file` and then the nasal demons will ensue. For me it's more trouble to have to decide when to quote the script and when I can not quote it so I just always quote it - safe and simple.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk -v ORS="\n\n" '{print}' file
aaaa

bbbb

cccc
```

Comment: Or just  `awk -v ORS="\n\n" '1' file`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only have spaces between lines and not have an extra blank line in the end:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { printf ORS } 1' file
```

Or

```
awk 'NR > 1 { $0 = ORS $0 } 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure bash soltion would be

```
while read line; do echo $line; echo; done < file;
```

Comment: to put this in a output 'while read line; do echo $line; echo; done < file > output;'

Comment: @josifoski That would be for all answers :)

Comment: question is to checkmark compact or teaching motivated answer, will reconsider :)

Comment: This will produce output that's wildly different from your input file contents given many different possible input file contents. Do NOT do this.

Comment: @EdMorton Interesting, I did not realize that. Can you be slightly more specific? And would it be solved with `echo "$line"`?

Comment: No. That would resolve the file name expansion problem where globbing chars in your input file can match against file names in your current dir, and it would solve the problem of white space between words being contracted, but it would leave the problems of leading and trailing white space and backslash chars being stripped. You need `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; echo; done < file` but any time you write a loop in shell just to parse a text file it's the wrong approach - just call the appropriate tool (e.g. awk or sed or grep ).